# How can I compare one element to all other elements while iterating over an array?

Tags: ruby

I want to write a function that, given an array of integers, and `number`, determines (returns true or false) if any two integers in the array sum to `number`.

I know I can iterate over the array once using `.each`.

What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to do the second loop i.e. sum the current element with each of the other elements.

How can I do this in an elegant way?

I am new to Ruby.

Comment: please give some examples with in- and output of what tou expect and the code that you tried.

Comment: Hint: [`combination(2).find`](https://rubyapi.org/3.0/o/array#method-i-combination).

Comment: Is the goal to find any pair, or all pairs?

Comment: @pjs, Just return 'true' if a pair exists, that's all.

Comment: The expected return type/value is a pretty important piece of information.  You should edit the question as suggested by @peter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def find_pair(array, num)
  array.combination(2).any? { |combo| combo.sum == num }
end
```

[combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-combination)

[any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

Comment: Just a comment to make sure it is seen: this may be pretty but is not practical, it is a quadratic solution (space and time!) to a linear problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a classic google interview question](https://youtu.be/XKu_SEDAykw). Here's a way for an `o(n)` time and space complexity:

```rb
require 'set'

def find_pair(array, sum)
  set = Set.new
  array.each do |i|
    return true if set.member?(i)
    set << sum - i
  end
  return false
end

raise 'it returns false when no pair found' unless find_pair([1, 2, 4, 9], 8) == false
raise 'it returns true when pair found' unless find_pair([1, 2, 4, 4], 8) == true
```

There is also an `o(n)` time `o(1)` space solution for a sorted array, I'll let you find it.

Comment: While the algorithm might be linear, the code does not look like Ruby at all. The OP mentioned they are a Ruby beginner, so it would be prudent to mention that you should never write code like this in Ruby. As a beginner, the OP might not be aware of that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What would your refactored version be?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I would use such code in production if need be... Please show us something else! I internally thought about using `Array#any?`, but I find this version much more clear in the end. And it _is_ ruby and tested on my end !